# How to extract the extension/type of all S3 objects frequently in a given interval and demonstrate in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-quicksight

I have some buckets in Amazon S3 which new objects with different types (json, jpg, mp4, sql files, PDF, log, and so on) are ingested to them each second.

I want to have a dashboard like the attached picture in you say QuickSight or Grafana which I could show the last status of my S3, including the total number and volume of each object type and a historical trend.
[image]

I could obtain the number and volume of objects by Glue Crawlers, but the problem is that I couldn't find any effective solution which able to extract every object types.

Glue crawlers don't recognize all types(for example jpg), and some other solutions like using AWS CLI or a python script to iterate the whole S3 each time to generate a report of all objects is not cost and time effective.

I was trying to utilize S3 Tags concept, but then I didn't know how to extract tags and have them as you say columns and query against them in for example Athena.

So, the question is what is an effective solution to obtain all objects info, especially the extension/type, to demonstrate in Quicksight.

Comment: Try **Amazon S3 Storage Lens**. This is a managed solution that you are trying to build by your own. Checkout - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-storage-lens/

Comment: @AnkushJain thank you Ankush for replying. I already tried Storage Lens, but it has two deficits, one is that its report's minimum interval is daily, so I can't have an updated dashboard for example for last 5 minutes, and the second is that its CSV report file only contains the total number and size of each bucket, without any info about extension/type of objects of that buckets. So I won't have info about each type volume/number.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend, create a Lambda, trigger it on S3 events, get metadata information in Lambda, store it in DynamoDB as per your access-pattern. Use DynamoDB data to generate report.

Comment: It does make sense for me Ankush, but the issue I faced before (but not sure) is that not all objects' metadata contains its extension/type or at least has correct metadata. So how I should be sure that the metadata of each ingested data from various sources contains the correct metadata?

Comment: You get the s3 key, and from this key you can retrieve the file extension. This should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [event-driven](https://aws.amazon.com/event-driven-architecture/) approach. [Subscribe an SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html) to putObject/deleteObject [S3 notification events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) for the bucket. Then create a process to consume the SQS queue messages to update a running tab of the file extensions (say, in a DynamoDB table or relational DB hooked up to QuickSight). This queue consumer could be a [lambda function triggered by the queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html) or just a simple application on any compute platform like EC2, [ECS scheduled tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/scheduled_tasks.html), or whatever!

This way, you don't have to repeatedly scan *all* objects to get the counts. You only have to periodically consume the SQS queue messages to update your counts for all the new object additions/deletions.

You only have to process the queue as frequently as you need for your report freshness (up to the SQS max message retention period of 14 days) and each run should be short, since it should just be the delta of events since the last run. So you could process in near-realtime if you wanted or as little as every 14 days. The event messages contain a timestamp, so data resolution could still be maintained even if you only process the queue periodically.

Comment: Good idea sytech. Just as I am somehow newcomer :), I don't know how to deploy some parts: 1- what do you mean by running tab of file extension. 2- which service or tool I need to process the queue. 3- Do you know any aws workshop or youtube video which help me understand and deploy these steps. Thanks!

Comment: @EhsanXan For (1) by running tab, I just mean a running count. For example, a DynamoDB table that stores a key-value pair of the file extension as the key and an integer count as the value. For each message processed, you would increment or decrement the count for a particular extension key depending on the message contents. For (2) I've added this additional context to my answer. For (3) I don't have any strong recommendations, but AWS architect/developer certification courses are a good bet. I've added some relevant doc links that may help.

Comment: Very helpful and complete guide @sytech, thanks a lot really. Just the last doubt, how can I extract the object's extension from an SQS queue? from its metadata or what? because as I check from AWS console, some of my objcts has metadata like this: Type:sytem-defined/ Key: Content-Type/ Value: application/octet-stream (this is an object which kinesis firehose has generated)

Comment: @EhsanXan Glad this has been helpful. The [event message structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) (which will be in the SQS message) will include details about the object, which will include the key (filename) of the object, which you can use to determine the extension. If needed, you could even use the key from the event message to retrieve more information or even read the file, if you wanted. If this helped answer your original question, please consider voting/accepting it.